# NullPointerException When Attempting To Bundle Extras Between a Service and Another Class

Tags: java, android, bundle, forceclose

I'm attempting to bundle extras between a service and another class I've built but I'm having trouble due to a force close error stating "java.lang.NullPointerException at com.test.generic.clientprovisioninghandler.DataCountService.onStartCommand(DataCountService.java:46)"

Which is the line Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Any suggestions as to how to correct this are greatly appreciated!

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your custom `getIntent()` method. I guess you wanted to use the intent passed as an argument :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Answer (score 3):

In you `DataCountService`  class ,You forgot to implement the below method :

```
private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Always returning null.

Implement your  logic there,and return the result.